# Using iCheck - event called twice on mobiles

Tags: angularjs, events, checkbox, icheck

I have a strange issue in one of my AngularJS apps. The app uses iCheck for styling checkboxes, and the issue is this: When selecting a checkbox by clicking on its label, **while on a mobile phone** (or a mobile emulator), the events tied to the checkbox are fired twice.

I've created a JSFiddle where you can reproduce the issue yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/o6oewfff/22/

```
 <input data-icheck data-ng-model="product.selected" id="{{product.id}}" type="checkbox" data-ng-change="callAnEvent()" />
```

**First, take a look at how it's supposed to work:**

1. Open the JSFiddle in your browser
2. Open the javascript console in your developer toolbar
3. Select one of the checkboxes **by clicking on the label** and you will see three log items in the console log: *Apply*, *Event called* and *Update*

**Now, let's reproduce the issue I'm trying to fix:**

1. Open the JSFiddle in a mobile emulator (try iPhone 6 for example)
2. Open the javascript console in your developer toolbar
3. Select one of the checkboxes **by clicking on the label** and you will see **five** log items in the console log: *Apply*, *Event called*, *Update*, *Event called* and *Update*

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j03S.png

As you can see, the events that are logging 'event called' and 'update' to the console are triggered twice when using a mobile. Also, the checkbox is not checked. Is anyone able to figure out why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: It has to do (at least partially) with the hover. Try disabling hover with `labelHover: false` and see if it makes a difference. On most touch devices, when there's something with hover, the first tap triggers the hover, the second tap is the actual "click".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this one a try https://jsfiddle.net/scdmuout/

I added in the below to stop it firing on the touch and click

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```